# ImportError: cannot import name 'json2csv' from 'nltk.twitter.util'

Tags: python, json, twitter, importerror

So i have ran the command on terminal  and installed json2csv but i still get the error that it cant import this module :

> ImportError: cannot import name 'json2csv' from 'nltk.twitter.util' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/twitter/util.py)

Help on what should i do to make this work . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the below code to install json2csv

```
pip install json2csv
```

in terminal on Linux or

```
!pip install json2csv
```

on Jupyter notebook directly

Comment: Also, from what I can observe, the "nltk.twitter.util" package doesn't contain "json2csv". 
I mean you can install it directly using pip like I have mentioned.